# Why isn't my fstream opening correctly?

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I feel like this is a silly question, but I can't seem to figure out why my file isn't opening. At first I tried passing the file name alone since it was in my working directory, and when that didn't work I supplied the entire path, which didn't work either. Is there a reason why my file wouldn't open in the following code? It's probably something very simple that I am missing, and I figured a fresh set of eyes might help.

There is no error code since this is a runtime error. When I debug, my code doesn't step past the `if(f.is_open())` line. Am I missing something? My path should be correct since I copy-pasted it directly from the file explorer.

Any help is welcome, and an explanation would be appreciated as well.

*Note: My substr logic may be wrong, but don't worry about that part of the code.*

```
 void QuizKey::readFromFile(string path)
    {

        fstream f;
        f.open(path);

        string line;

        if(f.is_open())
        {
            while(getline(f, line))
            {
                int periodLocation = line.find(".");
                int firstPipe = line.find("|");
                int secondPipe = line.find("|", firstPipe);
                int thirdPipe = line.find("|", secondPipe);

                AnswerSet set;
                set.answer = line.substr(periodLocation + 1, firstPipe - periodLocation - 1);
                set.two = line.substr(firstPipe + 1, secondPipe - firstPipe - 1);
                set.three = line.substr(secondPipe + 1, thirdPipe - secondPipe - 1);
                set.four = line.substr(thirdPipe + 1, line.length() - thirdPipe - 1);

                key.push_back(set);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Windows and you copy and pasted directly from Explorer then you might have forgotten to escape the slashes in the filepath, it should be `"c:\\foo\\bar.txt"`.

Also, doesn't `open()` take a `char*`, which would need to be `f.open(path.c_str())`?

Comment: C++11 added a `std::string` overload for `basic_fstream<CharT>::open`.

Comment: Ooh that's nice - I haven't got as far as C++11

Comment: I see the problem now: When copy pasting from explorer, I get an extra tidbit at the front: file:///C:/Users/Zachary/Documents/GitHub/Quiz_Maker/TestKey.txt which I forgot to remove. That fixed the problem, but your answer pointed me in the correct direction. Thank you. @MrZebra

Comment: IIRC forward slashes should work too: `"c:/foo/bar.txt"`

Comment: Yeah, forward slashes are fine, no escaping or other heroic measures necessary.

Comment: Yep you don't want the file:// bit.  @juanchopanza is also correct that / will work as well as \\